# Installing chemstyle package with OSX

Tags: packages, mactex, shell-escape

I used the (awesome) [chemstyle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemstyle/chemstyle.pdf) bundle to write several theses on my old PC (with MiKTeX), and would like to continue using it with my new mac (OSX). I *think* I've managed to install it okay at the command line using `sudo tlmgr install chemstyle`, but I'm unsure about where to proceed from there - I've read about needing to enable write18 (I tried `pdflatex --enable-write18`, but wasn't sure about what to do next). Any help would be much appreciated! When I try to compile previous projects (using texmaker), the numbers appear in order in the text, but the graphics still have the temporary numbers (TMP1, TMP2 etc). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What LaTeX distribution are you using? MacTeX? TeXlive? 2009? 2010? Does compiling multiple times help?

Comment: Could you post an example TeX file somewhere? Also, which editor do you use, or are you using the Terminal to run pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I'm using MacTeX 2010, I've tried compiling multiple times (from texmaker, have also tried TeXShop) but no joy. I've pasted my main file here: http://pastie.org/1166589 - with auto-pst-pdf included (after some googling), it fails with the error `"shell-escape" or "write18" is not enabled`.

Comment: This is not a good example. It is far too [long](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/647).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line argument you want to pass is `-shell-escape` to enable `\write18`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've given that a shot, but no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: @Sonia: I think you're misusing it. When I (try to) compile your example without `-shell-escape`, I get an error that it is needed. When I compile it as `pdflatex -shell-escape foo`, then it gets much farther before failing with a mysterious hyperref error that I didn't try to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I was trying to enable write18 for the wrong file...sorry about the n00b-ness!